# selecting a record with minimum null fields values in PySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have this spark data frame. I want to pick a record with a minimum number of the null fields out of multiple fields  -- say for more than 20 fields based windowing on ['facid','mrn','date','filetimestamp'

```
spark_df  = spark.createDataFrame([
   ('PMS.RCM','2442','2021-03-15T00:00:00','8c796c7ef314851c4','202104060445575041',None,None),
   ('PMS.RCM','2442','2021-03-15T00:00:00','1a644a8c08800e0b7','202104060445575041','0','1'),
   ('PMS.RCM','2442','2021-03-12T00:00:00','f5a79fa8beb64d6e4','202104060445575041',None,None),
],
 ['facid','mrn','date','mdsid','filetimestamp','e0300','v0200a14b'])
spark_df.show()
spark_df  = spark.createDataFrame([
   ('PMS.RCM','2442','2021-03-15T00:00:00','8c796c7ef314851c4','202104060445575041',None,None),
   ('PMS.RCM','2442','2021-03-15T00:00:00','1a644a8c08800e0b7','202104060445575041','0','1'),
   ('PMS.RCM','2442','2021-03-12T00:00:00','f5a79fa8beb64d6e4','202104060445575041',None,None),
],
 ['facid','mrn','date','mdsid','filetimestamp','e0300','v0200a14b'])
spark_df.show()
+-------+----+-------------------+-----------------+------------------+-----+---------+
|  facid| mrn|               date|            mdsid|     filetimestamp|e0300|v0200a14b|
+-------+----+-------------------+-----------------+------------------+-----+---------+
|PMS.RCM|2442|2021-03-15T00:00:00|8c796c7ef314851c4|202104060445575041| null|     null|
|PMS.RCM|2442|2021-03-15T00:00:00|1a644a8c08800e0b7|202104060445575041|    0|        1|
|PMS.RCM|2442|2021-03-12T00:00:00|f5a79fa8beb64d6e4|202104060445575041| null|     null|
+-------+----+-------------------+-----------------+------------------+-----+---------+
```

I want to have the data like this

```
dedup_cols = ['facid','mrn','eventdate','filetimestamp']
windowDedup = Window.partitionBy(*dedup_cols)
​
final_df  = spark.createDataFrame([
    ('PMS.RCM','2442','2021-03-15T00:00:00','1a644a8c08800e0b7','202104060445575041','0','1'),
    ('PMS.RCM','2442','2021-03-12T00:00:00','f5a79fa8beb64d6e4','202104060445575041',None,None),
],
  ['facid','mrn','date','mdsid','filetimestamp','e0300','v0200a14b'])
final_df.show()
+-------+----+-------------------+-----------------+------------------+-----+---------+
|  facid| mrn|               date|            mdsid|     filetimestamp|e0300|v0200a14b|
+-------+----+-------------------+-----------------+------------------+-----+---------+
|PMS.RCM|2442|2021-03-15T00:00:00|1a644a8c08800e0b7|202104060445575041|    0|        1|
|PMS.RCM|2442|2021-03-12T00:00:00|f5a79fa8beb64d6e4|202104060445575041| null|     null|
+-------+----+-------------------+-----------------+------------------+-----+---------+
```

Comment: Is there are reason the record with msid `f5a79fa8beb64d6e4` was chosen in the desired output instead of the record with msid `8c796c7ef314851c4`?

Comment: hi @ggordon those are two different dates (03/12 and 03/15)... I have two different dates and I want to get one record per date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a case expression, concat and length to count the number of nulls and row_number to prioritize the records you would like to select i.e. ordered by less nulls in each group/partition (partition fields cannot be null).

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import Window

dedup_cols = ['facid','mrn','eventdate','filetimestamp']
windowDedup = Window.partitionBy(*dedup_cols)

null_col_list = [F.when(F.col(col_name).isNull(),"|").otherwise("") for col_name in spark_df.columns]
(
    spark_df.withColumn("null_count",F.length(F.concat(*null_col_list)))
            .withColumn(
                "priority_num",
                F.row_number().over(
                    windowDedup.orderBy(F.col("null_count").asc())
                )
            )
    
).show()
```

```
+-------+----+-------------------+-----------------+------------------+-----+---------+----------+------------+
|facid  |mrn |date               |mdsid            |filetimestamp     |e0300|v0200a14b|null_count|priority_num|
+-------+----+-------------------+-----------------+------------------+-----+---------+----------+------------+
|PMS.RCM|2442|2021-03-12T00:00:00|f5a79fa8beb64d6e4|202104060445575041|null |null     |2         |1           |
|PMS.RCM|2442|2021-03-15T00:00:00|1a644a8c08800e0b7|202104060445575041|0    |1        |0         |1           |
|PMS.RCM|2442|2021-03-15T00:00:00|8c796c7ef314851c4|202104060445575041|null |null     |2         |2           |
+-------+----+-------------------+-----------------+------------------+-----+---------+----------+------------+
```

You may then filter based on the `priority_num=1`

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import Window

dedup_cols = ['facid','mrn','eventdate','filetimestamp']
windowDedup = Window.partitionBy(*dedup_cols)

null_col_list = [F.when(F.col(col_name).isNull(),"|").otherwise("") for col_name in spark_df.columns]
(
    spark_df.withColumn("null_count",F.length(F.concat(*null_col_list)))
            .withColumn(
                "priority_num",
                F.row_number().over(
                    windowDedup.orderBy(F.col("null_count").asc())
                )
            )
            .where(F.col("priority_num")==1)
            .drop("null_count","priority_num")
    
).show(truncate=False)
```

```
+-------+----+-------------------+-----------------+------------------+-----+---------+
|facid  |mrn |date               |mdsid            |filetimestamp     |e0300|v0200a14b|
+-------+----+-------------------+-----------------+------------------+-----+---------+
|PMS.RCM|2442|2021-03-12T00:00:00|f5a79fa8beb64d6e4|202104060445575041|null |null     |
|PMS.RCM|2442|2021-03-15T00:00:00|1a644a8c08800e0b7|202104060445575041|0    |1        |
+-------+----+-------------------+-----------------+------------------+-----+---------+
```

Let me know if this works for you.